# Realm Swift 2.0.4 Crash after logIn()

Tags: realm

*Realm 2.0.4, Swift 3.0.1, Xcode 8.1*

I'm getting the following crash after using the `SyncUser.logIn()` method:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.

I'm not doing anything with separate threads (that I know of) other than using the `SyncUser.logIn()` method like this:

```
//AuthForm.swift
let signUpCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: ..., password: ..., register: true)

SyncUser.logIn(with: signUpCredentials, server: serverURL) { user, error in
  if user == nil {
    //Error
  }else{
    //Success
    setupRealm(user: user!)
  }
}

//In another Swift file...
func setupRealm(user: SyncUser){
  // Create the configuration
  Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: realmURL))

  // Open the Realm
  _ = try! Realm()
}
```

The crash then occurs when my app loads and attempts to use a Realm for the first time. My assumption is that the realm that gets set up with the default configuration is different than the one accessed.

Attached is the breakpoint right before the crash. I have a breakpoint set for all exceptions, but the crash just points me to the top of my App Delegate.

[image: Xcode Breakpoint]

Oddly enough, after rebuilding my app in Xcode, it works and doesn't crash anymore. It's somehow related to the `logIn`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I had to wrap the entire contents of the `logIn()` closure in a main thread queue like this:

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: signUpCredentials, server: serverURL) { user, error in
  DispatchQueue.main.async{  
    if user == nil {
      //Error
    }else{
      //Success
      setupRealm(user: user!)
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Sorry you ran into this issue. We'll be updating our documentation and/or changing the way this API works in a future release to avoid such confusion.